# Inserting Worksheets Into Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to insert and name a new worksheet into an existing Google Sheet using java-script in the browser.

When using the Spreadsheets V3 API in [Google's OAuth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) to try to Insert a Worksheet (VIA the "Insert Worksheets" operation), I get an error 415: "Content-Type application/json is not a valid input type."

I've tried using all the default content-types Google provides in a drop-down, and they all result in the above error. I've been unable to find documentation for the Spreadsheets V3 API aside from what's in the OAuth playground.

Does anyone know the correct content type / how to insert a work sheet into a Google Sheet using java-script browser code?

Thanks!

Summary/Solution:

- **Google Sheets API v4** is the next version of **Spreadsheets v3** in the OAuth playground.
- The Reference section of the [Google Sheets API v4](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/) seems to be missing a lot of API details, but you can find them in the [Google Sheets API v4 migration guide](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/migration).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spreadsheets v3 is now a Legacy Version:
[image]

You can use [v4](https://developers.google.com/sheets/), and the [migration documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/migration) can help convert from v3 to v4. I've tried using the v4 in the OAuth 2.0 :

```
POST /v4/spreadsheets HTTP/1.1
Host: sheets.googleapis.com
Gdata-version: 3.0
Content-length: 61
Content-type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN
{
  "properties": {
    "title": "Test Sheets (local)2"
  }
}
```

This request successfully create a sheet in my drive:
[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I didn't realize Spreadsheets v3 in the OAuth playground is the same API as Google Sheets API v3 in the web documentation. With the help of the web documentation I have been able to get the "Insert Worksheets" operation to work in the OAuth playground.

Comment: I was also confused by the Google Sheets API v4 documentation. If you look under the [references section of the v4 documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.sheets), the copyTo method is the only method related to managing sheets within a Google Sheet. **HOWEVER if you look through the migration documentation you can find [how to add a new sheet to a Google Sheet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/migration#add_a_sheet_to_a_spreadsheet).** Thanks for the help, I wouldn't have thought to look thought that part of the documentation.